# matplotlib not generating PS output

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, ipython

I have installed matplotlib and using ipython
I have changes the backend to "PS" because the other backends werenot working

Now when I do

```
In [1]: plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
Out[1]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x23dc110>]

In [2]: show()
```

There is no output
I mean there should be a '.ps' file generated right?(please correct me if I am wrong)
but there is no such file in my pwd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `show()` command will display the image on the screen, not output it to a file in your working directory.  Since you have specified that 'PS' is your backend, nothing will appear and nothing is saved.  Try instead `savefig("foo.ps")` or even `savefig("foo")`, since your default is a PS, you don't need to specify the extension.  It will automatically output as a .ps.

Comment: Not a problem - I've added a bit more explanation to my answer, so you can understand what is happening.